# Fourier transform of tempered distribution example calculation

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory

I was watching a lecture from [Stanford](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s99rd_tIozY) on the Fourier transform on distributions since following the textbook for my course I was able to follow through the theory and proofs but not able to actually calculate the Fourier transform of a tempered distribution.

In the textbook we defined the Fourier transform $F[\phi]$ on a test (Schwartz) function $\phi \in \mathscr{T}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ by

$$F[\phi](\xi) := \int \phi(x) e^{i \langle \xi, x \rangle} dx.$$

So here is where the video differs from my textbook, namely, that the definition is

$$F[\phi](\xi) := \int_{- \infty}^{\infty} \phi(x) e^{-2 \pi i \xi x} dx.$$

So why are there two definitions? Is the second one just the one dimensional version and the video is considering $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$?

And the Fourier transform on a tempered distribution $f$ operating on a test function $\phi$ by

$$\langle F[f], \phi \rangle := \langle f, F[\phi] \rangle.$$

The lecture defines it the same way.

Now, then we actually calculate the Fourier transform of the $\delta$ function such that

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\langle F[\delta], \phi \rangle &= \langle \delta, F[\phi] \rangle \\
& =  F[\phi](0) \\
& = \int e^{i \langle 0, x \rangle}\phi(x) dx \\
& = \int 1 \cdot \phi(x) dx \\
& = \langle 1, \phi \rangle.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Thus, $F[\delta] = 1$.

The lecture arrives at the same solution but using the second definition of the Fourier transform of a Schwartz function.

So now, when we consider the example of the $\delta_{a}$ function which acts on $\phi$ by assigning its value at $a$, my calculations using the definition from the book differ from that in the lecture namely, I receive

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\langle F[\delta_{a}], \phi \rangle &= \langle \delta_{a}, F[\phi] \rangle \\
& =  F[\phi](a) \\
& = \int e^{i \langle a, x \rangle}\phi(x) dx \\
& = \langle e^{i \langle a, x \rangle}, \phi \rangle.
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

Thus, $F[\delta_{a}] = e^{i \langle a, x \rangle}$. And in the video (if one uses the second definition) he finds $F[\delta_{a}] = e^{-2 \pi i a x}$. Even if I substitute $n = 1$ in my calculation I do not arrive at $F[\delta_{a}] = e^{-2 \pi i a x}$, but instead at $F[\delta_{a}] = e^{i a x}$.

So am I making mistakes somewhere or what did I miss?

Comment: There are multiple definitions of the Fourier transform in common use, differing in the use of temporal vs angular frequency as well as the normalization. You also appear to have the somewhat odd convention of defining the forward transform with no minus sign in the exponent, which explains that part of the discrepancy.

Comment: @Ian thanks. So are my calculations correct using the definition of the textbook? Since I do not have solutions I cannot know.

Comment: @Ian hmm. I will probably email my professor and ask him about the minus sign convention because due to the Covid case, Sweden has transitioned to distance learning and we are assigned individual reading from the book and the book defines it as above.

Comment: With that convention it appears right.

Comment: Thanks. So if one adopts the definition using $-2 \pi i \xi x$, then in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ we would simply just take the inner product in the exponent i.e. $-2 \pi i \langle \xi , x \rangle$?

Comment: I think that's right, I am just slightly wary about the possibility of factors of $2\pi$ on the outside as a result of this form of $F$ not being unitary. Without playing with it on paper I can never remember where factors of $2\pi$ show up exactly, except when using a unitary normalization (in which case no extra factors of $2\pi$ show up anywhere).

Comment: @Ian It is how I said. It generalizes to the inner product. I found it in the notes written by the professor who held the lecture on p. 336 namely, here https://see.stanford.edu/materials/lsoftaee261/book-fall-07.pdf and the convention with the minus sign is just the duality of the inverse Fourier transform, where then the minus sign disappears. In my case it appears. Thanks a lot for clarifying things.

Comment: Because of the different ways to place $2\pi,$ some people even use an invalid equality; last year I read "assuming $2\pi =1$" in a paper. It should be interpreted as "the placement of $2\pi$ only changes some factors and not the central result."

Comment: @sloupo. Jaså, du är från Sverige!?

Comment: @md2perpe Jag bor i Sverige. Men jag kommer från Tyskland. Jag studerar i Sverige. And I am still learning Swedish and I only did my Bachelors degree there and now my Masters. But stuck in Germany atm due to Covid :)).

Comment: @sloupo. Wo in Deutschland wohnst du? Und wo in Schweden studierst du? Du kannst mir an Facebook schreiben: https://fb.com/md2perpe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105703/discussion-between-sloupo-and-md2perpe).